# How to correctly set round brackets size in small caps font?

Tags: fonts, formatting, brackets, text, small-caps

Let us consider my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pifont} % for dingbats
\usepackage{erewhon}% extension of Utopia,
\usepackage[varqu,varl]{inconsolata}% sans typewriter
\usepackage[scaled=.95]{cabin}% sans serif


\usepackage{textcomp}% AFTER newtxtext to avoid clashes
\usepackage[TM]{ar}


\begin{document}

\large\textsc{(LM 20)}

\end{document}
```

The output is: [image: output]

How to fit the round brackets size to the text `LM 20`?

P.S. This is a MWE that slightly differs from my project, where I have the font settings in a `.sty` file:

```
\ifdefined\@CorsoDiLaurea
                {\large\textsc{\@CorsoDiLaurea}}
```

and then in the `frontespiece.tex`:

```
\CorsoDiLaurea{ some text.... (LM 20)}
```

The line `\large\textsc{(LM 20)}` is placed in the frontespiece of my MSc thesis.

Comment: This is a font issue with `erewhon`. You could try to put the parentheses outside the smallcaps: `(\textsc{LM 20})`.

Comment: in general I would expect `\textsc{(}` to be ( seems to be a choice of this font...

Comment: @user574859 please read my edited question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a choice of the erewhon font setup. Whether by accident or design you would have to ask the author.

In theory you could make modified vf fonts for small caps that use full size parentheses but simpler is to use `\textup` to escape from small caps locally.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pifont} % for dingbats
\usepackage{erewhon}% extension of Utopia,
\usepackage[varqu,varl]{inconsolata}% sans typewriter
\usepackage[scaled=.95]{cabin}% sans serif


\usepackage{textcomp}% AFTER newtxtext to avoid clashes
\usepackage[TM]{ar}


\begin{document}

{\large Abc (LM 20)}


{\large\textsc{Abc (LM 20)}}

{\large\textsc{Abc \textup{(LM 20)}}}

\end{document}
```